# ブックマークレットが実行されない

Tags: javascript

js初心者です。

jsのコードをブックマークレットとして使用しているんですが、2行目の「ボタンをクリック」する処理が上手く動かず困っています。開発者ツールで要素を調べてみても`name="#btnAAA0"`となっています。原因を調べたいんですが、どんなことを試したらよいでしょうか。

```
javascript:!function(){
  document.forms['ABCD'].elements['ABCDE'].value = 'XX';
  document.querySelector("#btnAAA0").click();
}();
```

**追記**
sayuriさん

ご回答ありがとうございます。
クリックしたい要素のidやnameは以下のようになっていたので、JavaScriptの2行目を変更しました。

```
id=btnAAA0
name=btnAAA0
```

【2行目変更後】

```
document.querySelector("[name=btnAAA0]").click();
```

再度ブックマークレットを実行してみましたがやはりうまくいきません。

・画面の更新はされますが、意図したボタンを押した際の挙動とは異なります。
・一度だけ、上手くいきました。(いったように見えました。)

他に調べてみると良いことありましたらご教授願います。

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("#btnAAA0").click();
```

の部分ですが、

`"#btnAAA0"`でマッチするのは`id="btnAAA0"`です。
`name="#btnAAA0"`をマッチさせたいのであれば

```
document.querySelector("[name=#btnAAA0]").click();
```

こうすべきではないでしょうか？